# Using regex/String Method: Print Words containing Pattern

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a String, and a Pattern

```
myString = "thiS is testing my patience with regexIs";
pattern = "is";
```

I would like to loop through myString and print every word that contains the pattern. My dream output (**insensitive** to case) would be

```
"thiS is regexIs"
```

I know I would loop through the length myString, but I can't think of any string methods that  make sense in this case. I've counted for occurrences before(using stuff like charAt(i), matches, contains, replaceAll) , and have found patterns, index positions, special characters, numbers, etc. I'm in my first two weeks of real String method usage, but the stuff I've learned so far I cant piece together to figure out this puzzle.

Comment: [`.replaceAll("(?i)\\b(?:(?!\\w*is\\w*).)+\\b", " ").trim()`](https://ideone.com/IoYB2L)?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew While this is an impressive regex, I think a better approach might be to just split the string and use very simple Java string comparison methods.

Comment: when you have time can you please explain a little bit what everything means? regex script looks so foreign.  I understand replaceAll and that's about it :>

Comment: I hoped that a [**tempered greedy token**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed) is a matter-of-fact regex construct here already. My pattern is just that token within word boundaries, nothing fancy.

Comment: **▲** + **★**  regardless of first week of string methods. Nice question.

Answer (score 3):

The following method `findMatches()` returns a `List` of matching words in an input sentence.  You can use it to get the matches, and then print them out where you need to.

```
List<String> findMatches(String input, String pattern) {
    String[] parts = input.split(" ");
    List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (String part : parts) {
        if (part.toLowerCase().contains(pattern.toLowerCase())) {
            words.add(part);
        }
    }

    return words;
}
```

**Usage:**

```
String myString = "thiS is testing my patience with regexIs";
String pattern = "is";

List<String> matches = findMatches(myString, pattern);

for (String match : matches) {
    System.out.println(match + " ");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can split string to get the words in an array. Loop the array and compare them to your pattern.

```
String myString = "thiS is testing my patience with regexIs";
String[] arr = myString.split(" ");
for (String string : arr) {
    if (string.toLowerCase().contains("is")) {
        System.out.print(string+ " ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need loop for this at all.

```
String s = "thiS is testing my patience with regexIs";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("(?i)\\b((?!is).)+\\b", " "));
```